# Phoneword example emulation font scale incorrect

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, display

I'm a fairly new programmer and installed the Xamarin Android package for Visual Studio 2015.  I built and compiled the Phoneword example project without issues, but when I try to run the Android emulator, the fonts and size of the display are all wrong.

[image]

Does anybody know how to scale the fonts or fix this layout issue?
Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: What does the home screen of the emulator look like?  My first guess is that your emulator is running at a abnormal resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Steve, your emulator is most likely a problem.
These days Android emulator should not look like on your picture..

James Montemagno has a [good guide on configuring Android emulator for Visual Studio/Xamarin development](http://motzcod.es/post/154096351292/setting-up-android-x86-haxm-emulators). There is even a Youtube video on doing that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gDeH8-cAVZs

In the end you will have a fast starting, nice looking emulator even with Google APIs available (Maps, etc).

[image: correctly configured android emulator]

Also, very nice [quick start article on using VS 2017 for Xamarin](http://motzcod.es/post/158155898027/setting-up-vs-2017-for-xamarin-dev).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I really appreciated the pointers.  I have it fixed now.